# WebBackgrounder Register new job

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have configured WebBackgrounder in my asp.net mvc application and I have it working, I'm registering a job at the start of the application in WebBackgrounderSetup in App_Start.

Now I need to register another job from a controller action, how can I register it? I don't see any method for this in JobManager, isn't it possible?